# UITextView with @tags and hidden information behind the visuals

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to achieve same functionality as Facebook has with their post editor, where you can @tag people.
I was able to easily achieve coloring using NSMutableAttributedString and NSRegularExpression.

After user posts a text I need to send some more information. User can select the person from autosuggestion popup (already implemented, getting the name and data for user). Everything is working as long as I want to just keep @people format, but I can't.
The problem I have is is that I want to display @someone to user, but I need to keep more information in background, like userId for this person to pass it to backend later.

Check how Facebook does that - they don't even use @ sign, they just add some background color for name.

For example:

> Here I tag @myfriend and something else

That should result in information that @tag start from 10 and has 9 length and userId=100, so I'm able to color it and pass to backend information about who exactly user picked.
Also some additional functionality I want to have is to delete whole tag when user delete one letter from it.

I'm a bit struggling with this what would be the best way to do it.

**Idea 1:** Keeping 2 NSStrings, one having links in markupformat containing all data that lives in background and second one decorated to show to user.

**Problems:** Managing 2 NSString while user is editing is really painful, all NSRanges will be different for them and for example deleting tag from text will be tough. I tried to keep both synchronized but got so many problems with that and gave up.

**Idea 2:** Keeping an NSArray of references to tags when user is picking people to @tag with offset, length and showing user generated NSFormattedString which comes from combining a source text without any special markups and this information.

**Problems:** When user edits a text, ranges can change, for example if user deletes or adds some letter to my example before @myfriend, I will have to update offset for all tags after this, which can lead to some problems. More complicated will be if user selects a range of text and deletes it, than offset will have to be updated by more than 1.

Both sounds overcomplicated, problem is not easy I know, but maybe someone has some experience with such functionality or have some ideas how to solve that in some reasonable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for my problem was idea number 2.

I keep a text in UITextField + separately an array of all tags with their location and length - which is coming out of autocompletion views.

During

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

I update all tags that are after the range that will be changed by incrementing their location by `[text length] - range.length`

Also I have few more improvements that when user deletes a single letter from tag it whole dissapears. All done in this function works quite smoothly.

Based on those generated tag locations I decorate a text.

Comment: hi. could you please provide your code? i am looking for the exact same feature! thanks!